# Can MySQL Workbench display the number of selected rows in the query result grid?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I'm currently using MySQL Workbench to write very complex SQL Queries. To compare between different approaches, I need to know how many records have been returned by my query very quickly.

**So, is there any way I can see the number of records returned by my query in the result grid as soon as I execute it?**

I know that I can go to the 'Form Editor' tab and click on next and it will show me something like (2/179). But that's a very tedious process for me.

Comment: You could use a subquery in the `SELECT` list to return the count of your query in each row ([**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d002b/2)).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks Tim. I'm aware of this method as well. But first, it's more tedious and second, this won't work in my queries as they are very complex ones.

Answer (score 11):

The "Action Output" pane (the bottom vertical pane) has a "Response" column that tells you how many rows were returned.

Comment: I think it has been removed; I have "Action Output, Text output, History output" to choose from

Comment: The "message" column says X row(s) returned

Answer (score 1):

Philip Olson's way is a good one; yet another way is look at Query Stats in the same panel:

[image]

`Rows sent to client` is the one of interest; note `Rows examined` is not, as it shows how many rows the engine read to generate the results. (In this case, the operation was an inner join.)